# EF Core cannot update entity with two navigation properties to same object (other entity)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have two tables. User table has two links to another (identical) entity, i.e. Languages:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Language OrigLanguage { get; set; }
    public Language Language { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

EF creates the tables properly:

Table "Users": Id, FirstName, LastName, LanguageId, OrigLanguageId

I can add users with same values for OrigLanguage and Language w/o any problem.
As soon as I try to update and existing user with same values I get the following error message:

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Language'
>   cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id:
>   1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure
>   that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

with the following stack:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry
>   entry)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap.Add(TKey
>   key, InternalEntityEntry entry, bool updateDuplicate)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry
>   entry)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState
>   oldState, EntityState newState, bool acceptChanges)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState
>   entityState, bool acceptChanges, Nullable
>   forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode
>   node, bool force)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph(EntityEntryGraphNode
>   node, TState state, Func
>   handleNode)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph(EntityEntryGraphNode
>   node, TState state, Func
>   handleNode)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry
>   rootEntry, EntityState entityState, bool forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry
>   entry, EntityState entityState)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState(TEntity
>   entity, EntityState entityState)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Attach(TEntity
>   entity) Namespace.Data.Repository.UpdateAsync(T entity) in
>   Repository.cs

In my Startup.cs I have the following setting to prevent tracking:

```
services.AddDbContext<DocLogDBContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(...)
    .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)
```

In my repository I have the following code to update:

```
public override async Task<User> UpdateAsync(User entity)
{
    // below two detachments have no effect
    _context.Attach(entity.OrigLanguage).State = EntityState.Detached;
    _context.Attach(entity.Language).State = EntityState.Detached;
    _context.Attach(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return entity;
}
```

My API controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Edit(T model)
{
    await _repository.UpdateAsync(model);
    return Ok(model);
}
```

And this is the request from the client:

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44344/api/User/Edit
Request Payload: 
{
    Id: 3
    , FirstName: "Joe"
    , LastName: "Frazer"
    , Language: { Name: "english", ShortName: "en", Id: 1 }
    , OrigLanguage: { Name: "english", ShortName: "en", Id: 1 }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can resolved by using "[ForeignKey("xxxxx")]" atrribute on poco class.
Here I am trying to correct code as below:

```
   public class User
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       [ForeignKey("OrigLanguage")]
       public int OrigLanguageId { get; set; }
       [ForeignKey("Language")]
       public int LanguageId { get; set; }

       public Language OrigLanguage { get; set; }
       public Language Language { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.